# Site section hover capability disappears on certain resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I am developing this website.

110.140.56.58/public_html/green.php

I noticed something really strange while debugging the javascript shopping cart. The buttons for adding to cart are hoverable and have transition animations, but when the webpage is between the widths of 1000px and 1200px, none of the buttons are clickable, it's like there's an element on top of all the products. And the products all resize.

I will keep the local site up while this question is unanswered. I am completely confused by why this is happening. I'm guessing I have some kind of media query somewhere but inspecting the css on the resize isn't showing me anything useful. And no new elements are being drawn in the DOM.

Thank you, I hope this question is detailed enough.

Comment: man that website is too slow

Comment: @Rush.2707 lol dude I'm hosting it on adsl 2+ with 3.3Mb max download and .8Mb upload, mega bit btw. And the images are enormous but I forgot that it would load like a literal turd, sorry :( the real site is ozledgrowlights.com.au so you can compare how quick it should actually load, but the cart and issue isn't on the live site

Comment: Essentially it's your footer that's overlapping with your content since you haven closed your <div class="row">. I'm just assuming you didn't want your footer to live inside that div (?) :)

Comment: @localZero oh shit thank you!!! :) yay, it was just the </di> spelling error lol.. would you like to answer and I'll pick you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your footer that's overlapping with your content since you haven't closed your div with class="row". I'm just assuming you didn't want your footer to live inside that div (?) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the browser , or

Look for an html element that contain css style like ,
 `position: absolute;`

Which might be overlapping the buttons when the  page width increases , creating a blockage over *click events*(hover , transitions).